# How can I delete and rewrite a line without unknown characters?

Tags: python, algorithm, file

I have a database.txt file the first column is for usernames the second passwords and the rest 5 recovery question and answers alternating. I want to allow the user to be able to change the password of their details, without affecting another users username as they may be the same. I have found a way to delete the previous one and append the new line of modified details to the file. However, the is always a string or unknown characters at the start of the appended line. AND other characters are being changed not the second value in the list. Please help me find a way to avoid this.
https://repl.it/repls/NecessaryBoldButtonsYou can find the code here changing it will affect everyone, so please copy it elsewhere.

https://onlinegdb.com/BJbsn9-cL

I just need the password to be changed on a user input not other strings, the reason for all this code is that when changing a person's password another username could be changed.[This is the original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJtDu.png)

[This is what happens afterwards, the second string in the list of the line which where data[0] = "bye" should only be changed to newpass, not all of the others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwASr.png)

'''
import linecache

```
f = open("database.txt" , "r+")
for loop in range(3):
  line = f.readline()
  data = line.split(",")
  if data[1] == "bye":
    print(data[1])  #These are to help me understand what is happening
    print(data[0])
    b = data[0]
    newpass = "Hi"
    a = data[1]

    fn = 'database.txt'
    e = open(fn)
    output = []
    str="happy"
    for line in e:
      if not line.startswith(str):
        output.append(line)
    e.close()
    print(output)
    e = open(fn, 'w')
    e.writelines(output)
    e.close()

    line1 = linecache.getline("database.txt" ,loop+1)
    print(line)
    password = True
    print("Password Valid\n")
    write = (line1.replace(a, newpass))
    write = f.write(line1.replace(a, newpass))

f.close()
```

'''

This is the file in text:

username,password,Recovery1,Answer1,Recovery2,Answer2,Recovery3,Answer3,Recovery4,Answer4,

Recovery5,Answer5,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,

happy,bye,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,

bye,happy,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,

Support is very much appreciated

Feel free to change the code as much as you need to, as it is already a mess

Thanks in Advance

Comment: (1) You should not open the same file twice at the same time. (2) You can't insert or delete data in the middle of a file without writing also the rest of the file to the end (which you must read and store beforehand).

Comment: You want to change `happy` user password to from `bye` to `Hi`? And update the `database.txt` file with the new password without changing other lines, right?

Comment: @geckos On the third line I want to change bye to Hi, without altering anything else, only the second data column in each line (data[1]) should be changed, which is the password column.

Comment: So open the file, read it to memory, parse it so that you have list of lists or list of dict, after parsing changing only what you want would be easy, serialise it to a string again, write to another file, replace the old file by the new one.

Comment: It's a common practice to write contents to a new file then replace the old by new one by renaming the files, this make the file content to change "atomically". I left implementation as an exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty easy. The basic idea is:

```
open input file for reading
open output file for writing
for each line in input file
    if password = "happy"
        change user name in line
    write line to output file
```

It should be pretty easy to convert that to python.

From comments, and by examining your code, I get the feeling that you're trying to update a line in-place. That is, it looks like your expectation is that given the file "database.txt" that contains this:

```
username,password,Recovery1,Answer1,Recovery2,Answer2,Recovery3,Answer3, Recovery4,Answer4,Recovery5,Answer5,
o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
happy,bye,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
bye,happy,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
```

When you make the change, your new "database.txt" will contain this:

```
username,password,Recovery1,Answer1,Recovery2,Answer2,Recovery3,Answer3, Recovery4,Answer4,Recovery5,Answer5,
o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
happy,Hi,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
bye,happy,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
```

You can do that, but you can't do it in-place. You have to write all the lines of the file, including the changed line, to a new temporary file. Then you can delete the old "database.txt" and rename the temporary file.

You can't update a line in a text file, because if you change the length of the line then you'll either end up with extra space at the end of the line you changed (because the new line has fewer characters than the old line), or you'll overwrite the beginning of the next line (the new line is longer than the old line).

The only other option is to load all of the lines into memory and close the file. Then change the line or lines you want to change, in memory. Finally, open the "database.txt" file for writing and output all of the lines from memory to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the issue with this is that it will change happy in the fourth line too. I just need happy to change if it is in the second data on each line (data[1] , password column) not the first and that will be line 3. On line 3 bye changes to happy that is it, not bye in line 4. It changes based on password

Comment: @Daniel Then you change the `if username = ` thing that I wrote to `if password = `. The idea is that you can do this with a single, simple scan of the file.

Comment: Sorry, but I've tried this code and it doesn't change it in the file  `import linecache


f = open("database.txt" , "r+")
newpassword = "NEW"
for loop in range(3):
  line = f.readline()
  data = line.split(",")
  if data[1] == "bye":
    print(data[1])
    data[1] = newpassword
  

f.close()`